# How do you make a list in html/css become placed vertically when you shrink the page?

Tags: html

```css
p {
  word-spacing: 22px;
}

.pic {
  display: flex;
}

.navig {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.words {
  word-spacing: 22px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 563px) {
  .pic {
    display: table;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic"><img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50.png?text=Freaky+Fashion" alt="" />
  <p> <input class="navig" type="search"></p>
  <nav class="topnav">
</div>
<div class="words">
  <a href="#Nyheter">Nyheter</a>
  <a href="#Kategorier">Kategorier</a>
  <a href="#Topplistan">Topplistan</a>
  <a href="#Rea">Rea</a>
  <a href="#Kampanjer">Kampanjer</a></nav>
</div>
```

Hi I wanna know in html how can you put the list so it is formed vertically when you shrink the page like in the picture?

[I want it as it is on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLMYy.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code you misplaced HTML **nav** tag. Check the simple solution to get the nav list vertically at media screen (563px).

```css
p {
  word-spacing: 22px;
}

.pic {
  display: flex;
}

.navig {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.words {
  word-spacing: 22px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 563px) {
  .pic {
    display: table;
  }
  .topnav a {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic"><img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50.png?text=Freaky+Fashion" alt="" />
  <p> <input class="navig" type="search"></p>
</div>
<div class="words">
  <nav class="topnav">
    <a href="#Nyheter">Nyheter</a>
    <a href="#Kategorier">Kategorier</a>
    <a href="#Topplistan">Topplistan</a>
    <a href="#Rea">Rea</a>
    <a href="#Kampanjer">Kampanjer</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to code that in a single div?